# how to generate list of 5 random numbers between 20 and 100 in java

Tags: java, random

i want to generate list of 5 random numbers between 20 and 100.Here is my code

```
public class RandomNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println((int)(Math.random() * 10));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-to-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code (generates [from `0` to `80`] + `20` => [from `20` to `100`]):

```
public class RandomNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println((int)((Math.random() * 81) + 20));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Math.random can't return 1 so that can never return 100

Comment: @AaronDavis i fixed

Answer (score 1):

Make the calculation be `Math.random() * 81 + 20`

Answer (score 1):

This will generate 5 random numbers between 20 and 100 inclusive.

```
 public class RandomNumbers {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                System.out.println(20 + (int)(Math.random() * ((100 - 20) + 1)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This used import *java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom*;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(20, 100 + 1));
}
```

The nice thing is there is **no** number repetition and no need for prethought out math, which means changing values for max and min is incredibly **efficient** and **less prone to error**.